# sorting a numpy matrix on gpu

Tags: numpy, gpu, theano, pycuda

I have a large matrix - `1045506 x 3` which I want to sort based on the 1st column. Since, it's a numpy matrix, I can use argsort to get the result

`mat_sorted = mat[mat[:,0].argsort()]`

It takes about `69ms` to complete this step which seems a little to high to me.

My question is if there is a way to speed up the computation using the GPU? I was looking at some libraries like pycuda, theano but I'm finding it hard to understand the documentation. Specially, the part around passing numpy arrays and matrices to the gpu. Any pointers will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Interesting question. It is not obvious to me if there is a simple way to parallelize sorting operations in principle.

Comment: @roadrunner66: google "radix sort".

Answer (score 1):

There is no native sorting functionality in PyCUDA or scikit-cuda that I am aware of. However, efficient parallel sorting on the GPU is a mostly solved problem, and you can find state-of-the-art sorting algorithms in the Thrust template library, which ships with every version of the toolkit since about CUDA 4.0.

The PyCUDA wiki includes a [complete example](https://andreask.cs.illinois.edu/PyCuda/Examples/ThrustInterop) of calling the Thrust sort algorithm from PyCUDA.